# Discover EXT4 (or other) Linux file system (e.g. bootable?)

Tags: filesystems, ext4, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hdd

I want to be able to identify whether some older SATA HDD's have Linux partitions. With the advent (and my fairly recent discovery) of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows, I realize options have been improved, but i'm not sure it helps with just mounting an HDD (e.g. via SATA -> USB adaptor).

Larger task at hand: **Migrating from a Win 10 desktop to a new Mini PC**, I'm trying to find some extra space on existing HDD's for the operations. It's most likely that if it is an old Linux drive, and I don't know it, then it's probably nothing important.
[Win Disk Mgr screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/squQG.png)

I cloned a 1TB drive to recover media files (as it was imminent failure, and Linux was taking days to read the files). The cloning from faulty drive worked well for the files I wanted (see "Disk 1"), but the result left the "RAW" partition shown.

**Task specific to this inquiry**: Is it possible to "look at" that (or any other) partition via WSL, as might be attached (as shown in this instance) via SATA -> USB as "external HDD"?
Can I skip my concern and just format the RAW partition, knowing that there's nothing there based on the info in Win Disk Manager?

Best regards!

Comment: I wozld basically for easier management use a linux live boot and verify the situation

Comment: I have a bootable USB w/ Linux!  ...guess I was caught up in thinking about it from this Win 11 perspective. I guess I just hate migrating. I want it to be over, and just use that RAW space! :sigh as i boot into Fossapup: It is the right thing to do.

Comment: until WSL works like a native one, it is faster to boot from the USB and check the content, if you don't need the data, removing the partion is possible from windows. And it is possible to write to ntfs from but if possible you could consider using a other drive to speed up in case it's a hdd and not a ssd

Comment: sadly, it seems this mini-pc USB is malfunctioning. you can see it in the screenshot above, but not anymore. So, this USB boot idea isn't going to work. I have to send this thing back. if you want to know the manufacturer, PM me. moving it around, i realize there's something loose inside! i personally wouldn't recommend it for the quality of manufacturing, but the specs are good. it just "feels cheap". what can i expect for under $200...

Comment: that is the reason on serverfault.com why we only support business environment and business questions.

Comment: @djdomi , what is the reason? because WSL doesn't work as native? i don't understand. this is my business system.